# Como limpar/remover TODOS elementos do array em javascript?

Tags: javascript, array

Estou criando uma *calculadora em javascript* para melhor aprendizado e estou tendo dificuldade em `remover todos os elementos do array`. Sabe quando você clica no botão "`AC`" da calculadora e ele remove tudo? É isso que quero fazer.

**Meu código em HTML:**

```
<div class="row" id="btnTop">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-light"  id="AC" onclick="clicado(this.id)">AC</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-light"  id="/" onclick="clicado(this.id)">/</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-light"  id="x" onclick="clicado(this.id)">x</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-light"  id="<" onclick="clicado(this.id)"><</button>
            </div>
          </div> <!-- Fim btnTop -->

          <div class="row" id="btn789">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" id="7" onclick="clicado(this.id)">7</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" id="8" onclick="clicado(this.id)">8</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" id="9" onclick="clicado(this.id)">9</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" id="%" onclick="clicado(this.id)">%</button>
            </div>
          </div> <!-- Fim btn789 -->
```

**Meu código em JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      var i = 0;
      var clicks = Array();

      function clicado(id) {

          if (id != "AC" && id != "<") {

             clicks[i] = id;
             i++;

           // document.getElementById("mostrarValores").innerHTML = id;
            console.log("Array: "+clicks);

          }      

          if (id == "<") {

            clicks.pop();
            console.log("Array Removido: "+clicks);
          }

          if (id == "AC") {

            while(clicks.length) {
              clicks.pop();
            }

            console.log("Array Zerado: "+clicks);

          }

      }

    </script>
```

No stackoverflow mesmo eu encontrei respostas para remover assim:

```
while(clicks.length) {
   clicks.pop();
}
```

Que pelo que eu entendi, ele correria o `array` pelo tamanho dele e enquanto tivesse algo nele, ele iria removendo o último elemento até não ter nada.

Porém, quando eu testo no navegador, adiciono alguns números, apago com `AC` e depois adiciono outros números, o `array` começa com várias vírgulas. Notei que a quantidade da virgula, é a quantidade de elementos apagados anteriormente.

O problema é que eu queria que ao apagar com o AC, ele começasse do zero mesmo, sem as virgulas.

Segue a imagem do meu teste no navegador:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OBS: Já tentei clicks.length = 0 também e não adiantou.

Comment: Por que não redefine a array com `clicks = []`?

Comment: Tentei redefinir com clicks = [] e continuou o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando o botão `AC` basta você substituir o seu código

```
... while(clicks.length) {
          clicks.pop();
        } ...
```

por uma das opções abaixo:

1. `clicks = []; 
   i = 0;`
2. `clicks.length = 0;
   i = 0;`

Explicações abaixo:

> 1: Cria uma nova referencia para o array clicks fazendo com que ele zere todos os seus elementos existentes.
>
> 2: A semântica do JavaScript determina que, se você diminuir o
>   comprimento de um array, todos os elementos no novo comprimento e
>   acima devem ser excluídos.

Para limpar valores de qualquer array, usando uma das formas acima será valido em qualquer contexto, porém, você não reparou o seguinte: a **variável i**.
O problema era que quando você "zerava" os seus valores internos, a variável i não era zerada em conjunto, fazendo com que em sua construção `clicks[i] = id;` o array inserisse os seus valores a partir da variável i, por exemplo: se você inseriu os valores em sua lista 7,8,7 e em seguida limpou a variavel clicks, o i manteve o seu valor incrementado em cada i++(nesse caso 3), e aí é que o problema acontecia, quando clicado no `AC` e em seguida adicionado algum valor, o clicks[i] = id iria adicionar o id clicado na posição 3, por isso a explicação das vírgulas no array exibido no seu console!

Aconselho também alterar seu código do id:

```
  if (id == "<") {
    clicks.pop();
    console.log("Array Removido: "+clicks);
  }
```

Para:

```
  if (id == "<") {
    clicks.pop();
    if(i > 0 ){
        i--;
    }
    console.log("Array Removido: "+clicks);
  }
```

Espero ter ajudado e bons estudos!

Comment: Já fiz o teste dessas duas maneiras e tenho o mesmo problema. Quando digito os números e clico em AC, ele apaga tudo, imprime no console "Array Zerado: " porém, após eu apagar tudo, eu tento inserir mais numeros e daí imprime no console "Array: ,,,,5". (5 foi o numero que inseri). O problema é que no momento em que eu insiro mais números (após eu ja ter apagado o array), ele imprime com essas virgulas na frente.

Comment: 1 minuto vou usar seu código para ver em tempo de execução

Comment: Marcielli, encontrei o seu problema, vou editá-lo em minha resposta e você me diz se funcionou ok?

Comment: Ok, vou tentar aqui. Obrigada.

Comment: @MarcielliOliveira da uma olhada na resposta editada e me diga se funcionou ta?

Comment: Fiz as mudanças aqui e funcionou certinho. Obrigada.